# counting the lines in the text file having different types

Tags: sql, linux

i am using UTL_FILE utility in oracle to get the data in to csv file. here i am using the script.

so i am getting the set of text files

case:1

sample of output in the test1.csv file is

```
"sno","name"
"1","hari is in singapore
ramesh is in USA"
"2","pong is in chaina
chang is in malaysia
vilet is in uk"
```

now i am counting the number of records in the test1.csv by using linux commans as

```
egrep -c "^\"[0-9]"  test1.csv
```

here i am getting the record count as

```
2      (ACCORDING TO LINUX)
```

but if i calculate the number of records by using `select * from test;`

```
COUNT(*)
----------                 (ACCORDING TO DATA BASE)
        2
```

case:2

sample of output in the test2.csv file is

```
"sno","name","sal"
"","","1000"
"","","2000"
```

now i am counting the number of records in the test2.csv by using linux commans as

```
egrep -c "^\"[0-9]"  test2.csv
```

here i am getting the record count as

```
0      (ACCORDING TO LINUX)
```

but if i calculate the number of records by using select * from test;

```
COUNT(*)
----------                 (ACCORDING TO DATA BASE)
        2
```

can any body help me how to count the exact lines  in case:1 and case:2

using the single command in linux

thanks in advance.